# Reverse Engineering an APP With Frida

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to reverse engineer an app but I am having problems unlike the previous apps that I reverse engineered.....

When Untouched the app let's you login perfectly but when I reverse engineer it and repackage it( Without changing anything) I am getting a "Network Error"

I also tried using Frida and I am experiencing the same problem... does anyone know why this is happenning?

Answer (score 2):

*There could be multiple reasons for such a behavior to occur. Without more thorough investigation on your end and a more detailed description it's impossible to provide a good answer. Please take the [Tour](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how good questions are structured.*

However, what you're experiencing could be some kind of anti-patching protection, and the network related error suggested it might be related to some kind of server side verification.

Some ideas I can come up with:

1. An internal CRC or other code integrity blob (such as a cryptographic hash) is being sent to the server for validation.
2. A code integrity check is being performed and validated locally, only reporting the validation failure to the server or falsely reporting there's a network issue.
3. Your repackaging *does* change the application is some less obvious way which damages the application's ability to communicate with the server.
4. There's actually a network error, either due to your repackaging or for any other reason.